# How can I edit JavaScript from Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript

How can edit the source code of a website in order to modify its method? This is for a CTF challenge which involves exploiting the website but I cannot modify it in Microsoft Edge. I was able to do it on Chrome on another computer and tried it on mine, but it did not work either. What's the problem here?

EDIT: The problem that I have is that Edge won't allow me to modify the code. I try to double click on it but when I try to type something, nothing happens. In my case, I need to remove a few  lines of code to change the outcome when it works in order to get the flag but it won't allow me to. I also have checked my settings to allow experiments on the JavaScript and restarted my browser but it didn't work.

Comment: To get good answers, I think you might need to be a bit [more precise about what you want to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far? What result has that produced? What specific problems have you run in to?

Comment: I was just able to do it on Edge.. what exactly is the problem you're having? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to go to tab Experiments in DevTools and turn on appropriate option

[article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/21/announcing-the-latest-improvements-for-the-f12-developer-tools-in-windows-10/#KV3isQEuJhj4J8Ad.97)

Comment: Now in 2023, the option has been renamed / I cannot find it anywhere :)